# How do I get rid of all the smart quotes while parsing a web page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nltk, smart-quotes

This is my code:

```py
name = namestr.decode("utf-8")

name.replace(u"\u2018", "").replace(u"\u2019", "").replace(u"\u201c","").replace(u"\u201d", "")
```

This doesn't seem to work. I still find `&ldquo`, `&rdquo`, etc., in my text. Also, this text has been parsed using Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a *complete* test case so we can know precisely what you are asking. See http://SSCCE.org/ for more info.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the last line of your code with this one:

```
name = name.replace(u"\u2018", "").replace(u"\u2019", "").replace(u"\u201c","").replace(u"\u201d", "")
```

The `replace` method returns a modified string but it does not affect the sting you call it on so you have to assign the return value to the variable as above.