# Double opening and closing quotes

Tags: python, excel, text

I want to remove double open quotes and double close quotes from the text.

By Double opening quotes i mean **“** not **"**

I am trying to do it with python. But is unable to read **“**

Comment: What is the code you tried? Also, why did you tag this with Excel?

Comment: Are you trying to replace them with normal quotes, or just leave it blank?

Comment: Because i have got lot of this type of data in excel and i need to process that data using python. I tried to use replace function of excel but for most of the rows it gives me error that function is invalid. And in python i am unable to assign a text with “ to a variable. Filtering is too far to think of.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751636/how-do-i-get-rid-of-all-the-smart-quotes-while-parsing-a-web-page) should give you some ideas.

Comment: @sud_shan I'm confused as to how you used the replace function in excel. Could you show how you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

how about...

```
>>> s = "“hello“"
>>> s.replace('“','')
'hello'
>>>
```

Comment: Please read the question more closely -- he's specifically targeting the special character `“`, not the regular `"` mark

Comment: @adsmith hrm my mistake.  I've changed the code to replace the special character

Comment: @sud_shan yep, the '>>>' are the interactive interpreter prompts

Comment: I just copied the “ from adsmith's comment into my clipboard and then pasted it into the interpreter.  I'm using python 3.2 running in a linux shell.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you didn't want to say how you initially did it in excel, here's how you remove those:

- Option 1:

  Use the Find/Replace with find `“` and replace with nothing then find `”` and replace with nothing.

- Option 2:

  In excel, use `CHAR(147)` to have `“` and `CHAR(148)` to have `”`. Then `SUBSTITUTE` to remove them:

  ```
    =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(147), ""), CHAR(148), "")
  ```